# Redirect after form submission to a display form page

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, xslt

I have a Item Form to which I would like to add a redirect feature after submission.

```
 <button class="btn btn-default" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={https:my-url/Lists/AD_DB/newDisplay.aspx?ID=xxxx}')}" name="btnSave">Save</button>
```

Is there a way to transfer the Item ID (xxx) to the redirect url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `concat` function as below

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__commit;__redirect={https:my-url/Lists/AD_DB/newDisplay.aspx?ID=',$ID,'}'))}" name="btnSave">Save</button>
```

Assuming $ID has the ID value.

Comment: Perfect, you just missed a ")" after ...`$ID,'}')}`, I changed to ....`$ID,'}'))}`. The other thing I did was to change from $ID to @ID and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @cubanGuy I updated the answer. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

If your form is of the same list, here is a little bit nicer solution:

```
<SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="gobackbutton2" RedirectUrl="DispForm.aspx?ID={$ListItemId}"/>
```

In this case you don't need to specify the url, since it might change.

Don't forget to add the param to the stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
    <xsl:param name="ListItemId"></xsl:param> // <-- do not forget!

    // custom definition of the form

</stylesheet>
```