# Redirect to Display Form page after new item created

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, xslt

I have created a custom New Item Form, and customized the Save button to redirect to the Display Form after submission. I asked a similar question, and it was gratefully answer by @Amal ([here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/120317/redirect-after-form-submission-to-a-display-form-page)). The difference is that that works for the Edit Form, but not for the New Item form.

My Button:

```
<button class="btn btn-default" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent(concat('__commit;__redirect={https:my-url/Lists/AD_DB/newDisplay.aspx?ID=',@ID,'}'))}" name="btnSave">Save</button>
```

The issue is as I suspect that @ID is null at the moment of submission. What can I do to push the new item ID into the URL? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below JavaScript

```
fd.onsubmit(function() {
    var uri = fd.setUrlParam(decodeURIComponent(window.location.href), 'FDRedirectWithID', 'fd_Item_Edit.aspx?ID=');
    fd.sourceFormParam(uri);
    return true;
});
```

For more read [this](http://formsdesigner.blogspot.com/2013/10/how-to-open-edit-form-right-after.html?m=1)